# Could NOT find Boost in ubuntu machine?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, cmake

I have already installed BOOST in my brand new Ubuntu 12.04 machine. And when I do like this -

```
cmake .
```

I always get the below exception saying -

```
Could NOT find Boost
```

I am not sure what wrong I am doing here. I have one of my ubuntu instance working fine and I am trying the same thing on my new Ubuntu instance which I have got.. So I am not sure what wrong I am doing here and how the same thing works fine in my other ubuntu instance.

```
root@dbx1245:/export/home/test/libcql# cmake .
-- Could NOT find Boost
WANT_LIB64 unset; assuming normal library directory names
Will install libraries to /usr/local/lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /export/home/test/libcql
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I have seen other article as well on the stackoverflow but I am not able to solve this issue.

I already have boost installed by the way.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCEE](http://sscce.org/) for a CMakeLists.txt that reproduces the problem. After that, please check that you have the expected files: You need at least the `config.hpp` in `/usr/include/boost` and the `libboost*.a` files in `/usr/lib`. If any of those are missing, your local installation is corrupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also encountered this error - boost was correctly installed as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19993883/2597135).

I solved it by setting

```
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /usr/include)
```

just before

```
find_package(Boost)
```

I was using CMake 3.1.3 for testing (via `ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x`)